# convert String to int to get a unique number

Tags: java, android, string, int

hi i am trying to convert a sting such as "abc-d1_23QWEwer" to an int number

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int intServiceName = 0;
String stringServiceValue;
for (int i = 0; i < serviceName.length(); i++){
    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "serviceName.length() loop i: " + i);
    sb.append(String.valueOf(Character.getNumericValue(serviceName.charAt(i))));
    if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "serviceName.length() loop i after: " + i);
}
if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "serviceName.length() loop end2");
stringServiceValue = sb.toString();
if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "serviceName.length() loop end: "+stringServiceValue.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
stringServiceValue = stringServiceValue.replaceAll("\\D+","");
if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "serviceName.length() loop endstringServiceValue: "+ stringServiceValue);
intServiceName = Integer.parseInt(stringServiceValue);
if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "serviceName.length() loop end123123: "+ String.valueOf(intServiceName));
```

i am getting an error when the code reaches this line:

```
intServiceName = Integer.parseInt(stringServiceValue);
```

what am i doing wrong? this is the error log

```
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2914282912918292114"
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at com.wr.noc.AsyncTasks.doInBackground(AsyncTasks.java:113)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at com.wr.noc.AsyncTasks.doInBackground(AsyncTasks.java:1)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: How is "abc-d1_23QWEwer" considered to be an integer? Are you wanting to extract the digits out of it? If so, you need the parsing logic of your own.

Comment: that is why i am using Character.getNumericValue()

Comment: Wouldn't the .hashCode() function of string be much easier and simpler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use long instead of integer. your number is too big
you could do something like this if you need an int not a long

```
sb.append(String.valueOf(Character.getNumericValue(serviceName.charAt(i))).substring(0, 1));
```

Answer (score 5):

Observe :

```
06-21 19:12:54.760: E/AndroidRuntime(11139): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2914282912918292114"
```

I think it goes overflow, you might use a long instead.

Answer (score 2):

The number 2,914,282,912,918,292,114 is too big to fit in an int.  It *just* fits inside a long (the max value for a signed long is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807), so you could do

```
long l = Long.parseLong(someString);
```

Although a better solution would be to ask yourself why you need numbers that are so huge.  A redesign of your algorithm to avoid having such large numbers would make things easier as you go on.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is too large for an int. Consider to use a long :

```
numServiceName = Long.parseLong(stringServiceValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your number `2914282912918292114` is too large to be an `int` . The largest value `int` can hold is `2,147,483,647`. You need to use `long`which can hold maximum value of `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

```
 Long.parseLong(yourString);
```

If you are dealing with huge numbers , you can use the [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class for integers and [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for numbers with decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

go through the whole string like this:

```
// not sure if the syntax is correct

int myInt[] = new int[myString.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
    myInt.add(myString[i]);
```